# What's the significance of self inside of a method?

Tags: iolanguage

I'm reading through Seven Programming Languages in Seven Weeks, and one of the problems states:

How would you change `/` to return `0` if the denominator is zero?

I first tried defining my own `/` and proxying its implementation to the original `/` method like this:

```
Number oldSlash := Number getSlot("/")
Number / = method(x, Number oldSlash(x))
```

However that was not working for me. After doing some Googling I found a similar piece of code. The code I found was using `self` in the implementation of the method. So, I tried using `self` and it seemed to work just fine:

```
Number oldSlash := Number getSlot("/")
Number / = method(x, self oldSlash(x))
```

My question is: *Why does this work when the keyword `self` is used, and why does it not work when `Number` is used instead?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short version:**

`Number` is a "base class" for numbers; not an actual numerical value. You can't use it for mathematical operations. `self` represents the object your method was invoked on, which turns out to be the number you want to use as numerator in your division.

**The longer version:**

First, some background: Division as you know takes two arguments. The method you're defining only takes one argument (the `x`). The other argument is implicit and it's the Number you're invoking the division on. To make it crystal clear, when you're writing `a / b` the method `/` is invoked on the object `a` and it gets passed the value `b` as parameter. In a more C-like language, you'd say something like `a.divide(b)`. You don't pass `a` as a parameter, but it is accessible from the function anyway, as `self`.

So, using what we know from above, writing `self oldSlash(x)` performs division using `self` as numerator and `x` as denominator. The value of `self` is set when your "newSlash" method is called, once again implicitly to the object you're calling the method on. If you're familiar with JavaScript, `self` is Io's name for `this`.

When instead you write `Number oldSlash(x)` you use the object `Number` as the numerator in the division. `Number` is not an actual number, but rather the "base class" for all numbers. It does not have a value. Hence you cannot perform mathematical operations on it.

Comment: Ohhh. I Should have realized that on my own... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Io Programming Guide](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/IoGuide.html#Embedding-Conventions)

> All methods (except new) have the structure (the "object") as the
>   first argument the variable is named "self".

But you can omit `self`, is implicit:

```
Number oldSlash := Number getSlot("/")
Number / = method(x, oldSlash(x))
```